# Using static files in custom 404/500 pages in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, http-status-code-404, django-staticfiles

I would like to use some custom CSS and images on my custom `404/500` pages that I made.  Django doesn't include the `STATIC_URL` variable in those pages though.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  I also tried making a custom `404/500` view and rendering an arbitrary HTML file but it didn't work out so great.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
# urls or settings
handler500 = 'mysite.views.server_error'

# views
from django.shortcuts import render

def server_error(request):
    # one of the things ‘render’ does is add ‘STATIC_URL’ to
    # the context, making it available from within the template.
    response = render(request, '500.html')
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

It's worth mentioning the reason Django doesn't do this by default:

> “The default 500 view passes no variables to the 500.html template and is rendered with an empty Context to lessen the chance of additional errors.”
>
> -- [Adrian Holovaty, Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view)

Comment: so how would I reference my static files?

Comment: This adds `STATIC_URL` to the template's context. So you can use it as you normally would.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem and found a solution which doesn't need custom templates or handlers. From Django 1.4 on you can use the tags get_media_prefix and get_static_prefix to access MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL when they are not in the context.

In my particular case (Django 1.5), I wanted to access some static images in my page 500.html. I just added at the beginning of the template

```
{% load static %}
```

and then obtained the media and static urls with these tags

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}logo.png">
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/error_pages/error.png" style="height:235px;">
```

You can find the official documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're just going to have to override the default 404/500 error handling. This should get you started:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Comment: What happens when you try to include `{% load static from staticfiles %}` in the custom view?