# Serving static files in django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My `404.html` page does not reference my `finale.css` file.
My directory structure

```
musicworld/
   musicworld/
           __pycache__
           __int__.py
           settings.py
           urls.py
           wsgi.py
   feature/
           __pycache__
           migrations
           static/
                 feature/
                        finale.css
           templates/
                 feature/
                        about.html
                        detail.html
                 404.html
                 500.html
                 index.html
                 template.html
            __init__.py
            admin.py
            models.py
            tests
```

This is where in `index.html` I'm referencing the css

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'feature/finale.css' %}" />
```

But `404.html` that extends `index.html`is not referencing the css

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block 404page %}
<div class="box">
<p class="box-message" data-dead-message="AAAAAHHHHHH!">Oh No! Something went wrong.Punish the developer by clicking here.</p>
</div>

  <div class="robot">
    <img src="" alt="Robot" />
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

`static reference in settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Both the `index.html`and `template.html` are placed in the same folder and are properly referencing the css.Plus all the `html` pages in feature that are extending `index.html` are also referencing the css.But both `404.html` and `500.html`are not.

Comment: What is your `STATIC_URL` setting in `settings.py`? Have you run the [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/) command?

Comment: @tatlar `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. Never seen that command.New to django. But if it was necessary the other templates wouldn't be referencing the css file.Would they?

Comment: Show all lines containing `static` in settings.py. It might be something there.

Comment: @AbhiP I've edited that part into the code.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121731/using-static-files-in-custom-404-500-pages-in-django